# sub/gsub и Разделение двух слитно написанных слов в R

Tags: регулярные-выражения, r

Допустим есть строка в которой я хочу удалить все что находится перед "ключевым" словом. Для этого я использую:

```
sub(".*Вечер:", "", df)
```

Проблема в том, что иногда в строке появляются слитно написанные слова, например: добрыйВечер, холодныйВечер, приятныйВечер, но при этом "ключевое" слово всегда с большой буквы. Код который я использую в этом случае не находит паттерн. Есть у кого-то идеи как можно было бы удалить все, что находится перед "ключевым" словом в этой ситуации? И есть ли возможность разделить такие слова когда регистр переходит от нижнего к верхнему?

Answer (score 1):

Можно «захватить» часть строки с помощью круглых скобок и использовать порядковый номер захваченного выражения (`\1`).

```r
x <- c("добрыйВечер", "холодныйВечер", "приятныйВечер")
sub(".*(Вечер)$", "\\1", x)
```

Пакет `stringi` предоставляет широкие возможности по работе со строкам.

Извлечение подстроки (без шаблона):

```r
> stringi::stri_extract_all_fixed(x, "Вечер", simplify = TRUE)
     [,1]   
[1,] "Вечер"
[2,] "Вечер"
[3,] "Вечер"
```

Разделение строки по символу в верхнем регистре:

```r
> stringi::stri_split_regex(x, "(?=\\p{UPPER})")
[[1]]
[1] "добрый" "Вечер" 

[[2]]
[1] "холодный" "Вечер"   

[[3]]
[1] "приятный" "Вечер"
```

Подробнее по обозначениям в регулярных выражениях ICU можно прочитать на странице справки `?stringi-search-regex`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а разделить слова при смени регистра можно ?

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: Не могли бы вы посмотреть на код : sample_subseted$titles %like% "([\\s+jesteś osobą,])")  у меня в строке есть паттер перед которым я хочу удалит все, если я использую этот код, то мне выдает TRUE в том смысле что он в строке есть, если я  ([\\s+jesteś osobą,]) в gsub  как паттерн, то на выход получу околесицу

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @HermanCherniaiev `[\s+jesteś osobą,]` найдёт пробельный символ, `+`, `j`, `ś` и т.д., т.е. не последовательность символов, а один из символов в символьном классе.